# PreferenceFragment: start AlertDialog in onSharedPreferenceChanged()

Tags: android, android-preferences

I am trying to show an `AlertDialog` message when a `SwitchPreference` is clicked. I was trying to use `this`, but I got an error: *The constructor AlertDialog.Builder(Settings) is undefined*. So I used `getActivity()`, but this method doesn't show anything.

Also does anyone know how to do different actions between selecting the preference and selecting ticking the box. You know how in some setting you can click on the preference text and it will give you a description, then you have to click the small box to actually enable/ disable.

```
public class Settings extends PreferenceFragment implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener{

    Bundle savedInstanceState;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);

        this.savedInstanceState = savedInstanceState;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
        if (key.equals("this")) {
            final SwitchPreference sp = (SwitchPreference) getPreferenceScreen().findPreference(key);
            if (sp.isChecked()) {
                System.out.println("enabled");
            } else {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                builder.setMessage("blah...")
                        .setTitle("Title")
                        .setPositiveButton("proceed", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                System.out.println("positive");
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                sp.setChecked(true);
                                System.out.println("cancled");
                            }
                        })
                        .create();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you finish building your `AlertDialog`, the last call should be [`AlertDialog.Buidler.show()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#show%28%29), not [`AlertDialog.Builder.create()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#create%28%29). But if you call `create()`, later you can use [`Dialog.show()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#show%28%29).

Another note, you might want to use [`Log`](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html) to debug, not `System.out`.

Comment: You can still use `System.out` to debug, it will show up under the `Info` category.